# onsubmit didn't submits form even on return true from ajax verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax function on my form to check duplicate accounting code, but the form won't submitting even though there's no duplicate (that have to be submitted and processed to insert to database).

Here's my Html code :

```php
<form action="<?php print base_url(); ?>input/insertLedgerGroup" name="form_ldgroup" onsubmit="return checkDupCode()" id="frmledger" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

my Ajax code :

```
 function checkDupCode() {
            var c1 = document.forms["form_ldgroup"]["coa1"].value;
            var c2 = document.forms["form_ldgroup"]["coa2"].value;
            var wrn1 = "Coa Code";
            var wrn2 = "Sudah Terpakai !";

            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "<?php print base_url()."input/checkDupCoa"; ?>",
             data: {"hsl": c1, "hsl2": c2, "csrf_token" : $("input[name=csrf_token]").val()},
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(hasil) { 
                if(Object.keys(hasil).length>0){
                    alert(wrn1+" "+hasil['code1']+"."+hasil['code2']+" "+wrn2); 
                }else{
                    $("#frmledger").submit();
                }   
             }
            });

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$('#frmledger')` be `$('#frmasd')`?

Comment: the id on the form is same id="frmledger ", sorry forgot to change it

Comment: You're going to have an infinite loop then. You submit the form, which immediately returns false, cancelling the submission. Once the ajax call completes, it submits the form, which immediately returns false, cancelling the submission. The ajax call gets triggered again, starting the cycle all over again. At no point is the form actually submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call:

```
$("#frmledger").submit();
```

is like calling your **checkDupCode** function again and again. But every time you call this function you return false, no submit.

In order to avoid this you can use the [HTMLFormElement.submit()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) element method. In this way you don't call again your **checkDupCode** function.

In the following snippet I added the [error callback](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) in order to create the evidence:

```js
function checkDupCode() {
    var c1 = document.forms["form_ldgroup"]["coa1"].value;
    var c2 = document.forms["form_ldgroup"]["coa2"].value;
    var wrn1 = "Coa Code";
    var wrn2 = "Sudah Terpakai !";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "input/checkDupCoa",
        data: {"hsl": c1, "hsl2": c2, "csrf_token": $("input[name=csrf_token]").val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (hasil) {
            if (Object.keys(hasil).length > 0) {
                alert(wrn1 + " " + hasil['code1'] + "." + hasil['code2'] + " " + wrn2);
            } else {
                $("#frmledger").submit();
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#frmledger")[0].submit();
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="<?php print base_url(); ?>input/insertLedgerGroup" name="form_ldgroup" onsubmit="return checkDupCode()"
      id="frmledger" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" name="coa1" value="coa1">
    <input type="text" name="coa2" value="coa2">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```